# How to calculate power in non-central F distribution with very low variance?

Tags: r, distribution

I have a problem with my samples variance for calculating power in non-central F. 
When I run the code on R it says: (convergence failed in 'pnbeta')
Can you please let me know how I can fix it?
R code follows:

```
 x <- c(0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,0.05,0.06,0.07,0.08,0.09,0.1)
 y <- c(0.016189,0.019478,0.022767,0.026056,0.029345,0.032634,0.035923,0.039212,0.042501,0.04579)
 n0 <- length(x) 
 n0
 alpha <- 0.05 
 beta <- 0.80 
 delta <- 0.2
 m <- mean(x)
 m
 sxx=sum((x-mean(x))^2)
 sxx
 sxy=sum((y-mean(y))*(x-mean(x)))
 sxy
 b1hat=sxy/sxx
 b0hat=((mean(y)-(b1hat*mean(x))))
 b0hat
 yhat= b0hat + b1hat*x
 yhat
 sigma2=sum((y-yhat)^2)/(n0-2)
 sigma2
 ncp=n0*(delta^2)*((1+mean(x))^2)/sigma2
 power=(1-pf(qf((1-alpha),2,n0-2),2,n0-2,ncp))
 ncp
 power
```

Comment: The crux of the issue is that your `y` is essentially a linear function of your `x`. So the your residual variance  `sigma2` is `1.805559e-35` which is essentially 0. This makes your non-centrality parameter essentially infinite. You should start with a `y` that is not a linear function of `x`, such as adding some normal noise using `rnorm` for example.

Comment: Great comment. Thanks!

Comment: @ngm another way of looking at the problem is that the power is essentially 1.